# How can I make a configure script using autoconf on MSYS/MINGW?

Tags: c++, mingw, configure, autoconf, msys

I'm trying to use IT++ library in Windows 10. To this end, I need to make a "configure" script from "configure.ac.in" file which provided in IT++ library using autoconf on MSYS.
I encountered these errors:

Ahmad@AHMADTANHA /c/itpp-4.3.1
$ autoconf configure.ac.in
/c/MinGW/bin/autoconf-2.68: line 501: /mingw/bin/autom4te-2.68: No such file or directory
/c/MinGW/bin/autoconf-2.68: line 501: exec: /mingw/bin/autom4te-2.68: cannot execute: No such file or directory

Answer (score 3):

MSYS is old and slow, please use MSYS2. You can download it here:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/msys2/files/Base/

To use use it first extract the file (e.g. `msys2-base-x86_64-20200903.tar.xz`) and then under the `msys64` (or `msys32`) folder run `autorebasebase1st.bat` and reboot.

After rebooting start `mingw64.exe` (or `mingw32.exe`) and run:

```
pacman -Syu --noconfirm
pacman -S --noconfirm git wget tar gzip autoconf automake make libtool patch unzip xz bison flex pkg-config
pacman -S --noconfirm mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc
```

(for 32-bit the last line should be `pacman -S --noconfirm mingw-w64-i686-gcc`)

Exit the shell end open it up again. Now you should have a working environment.

Comment: Thanks for the input on my query!
I followed the steps you proposed, but I encountered these errors after running the following command in MSYS2:
$ autoconf configure.ac.in 

" >&6;}
configure.ac.in:28: error: possibly undefined macro: AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
configure.ac.in:50: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_DISABLE_SHARED
configure.ac.in:51: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_ENABLE_STATIC
configure.ac.in:58: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_ENABLE_SHARED

Answer (score 0):

When I look in the source code of IT++ I don't see a file `configure.ac` or `configure.am`, only `configure.ac.in`. However there is a file `CMakeLists.txt` which means the project should probably configured with CMake.

As a general rule if you can avoid the configure tools by using a more modern build system like CMake or Ninja, you should do so. Also, CMake supports Ninja which is a lot faster than `make`.

So I tried to build IT++ both static and shared with CMake like this and had no problems:

```
INSTALLPREFIX=/usr/local
cmake.exe -Wno-dev -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=OFF -DITPP_SHARED_LIB:BOOL=OFF -DHTML_DOCS:BOOL=OFF -S. -Bbuild_static &&
ninja -Cbuild_static install/strip &&
cmake.exe -Wno-dev -GNinja -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$INSTALLPREFIX -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON -DITPP_SHARED_LIB:BOOL=ON -DHTML_DOCS:BOOL=OFF -S. -Bbuild_shared &&
ninja -Cbuild_shared install/strip &&
echo Success
```

If for some reason you still want to use `make` instead of `ninja` you can replace `-GNinja` with `-G"MSYS Makefiles"`.

Comment: Excuse me, where did you write these lines of codes ?!
I mean which workspace did you use to build IT++ (MSYS2 or another environment)?

Comment: MSYS2 with cmake.exe and ninja.exe in my PATH (you can download them from from https://cmake.org/download/ and https://github.com/ninja-build/ninja/releases respectively).